# What is the difference between .m3u8 and .m3u playlists types?

Tags: itunes, playlist

iTunes will export a few different kinds of playlists, including .m3u8 and .m3u types.  What is the difference between these two file types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.m3u8` is simply a [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) version of the M3U format [[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U)]. (`.m3u` files can have [various encodings](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/m3u8).)